# How to move data from S3 to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a few questions regarding the process of copying tables from S3 to Snowflake.

The plan is to copy some data from AWS/S3 onto snowflake and then perform some modeling by DataRobot

1. We have some tables that contain PII data and we would like to hide those columns from Datarobot, what suggestion do you have for this problem?
2. The schema in AWS needs to match the schema in Snowflake for the copying process.

Thanks,

Mali

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the schema of the data you are loading, you have a few options for using Snowflake:

1. Use `COPY INTO` statements to load the data into the tables
2. Use `SNOWPIPE` to auto-load the data into the tables (this would be good for instances where you are regularly loading new data into Snowflake tables)
3. Use `EXTERNAL TABLES` to reference the S3 data directly as a table in Snowflake.  You'd likely want to use `MATERIALIZED VIEWS` for this in order for the tables to perform better.

As for hiring the PII data from DataRobot, I would recommend leveraging Snowflake `DYNAMIC DATA MASKING` to establish rules that obfuscate the data (or null it out) for the role that DataRobot is using.

All of these features are well-documented in Snowflake documentation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding hiding your PII elements, you can use 2 different roles, one would be say data_owner(the role that will create the table and load the data in it) and another say data_modelling (for using data robot)

Create masking policies using the data owner such that the data robot cannot see the column data.

About your question on copying the data, there is no requirement that AWS S3 folder need to be in sync with Snowflake. you can create the external stage with any name and point it to any S3 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake documentation has good example which helps to get some hands on :

```
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3.html
```